# Update CentOS Security Patches

Tags: centos, yum

I need some help as I am really struggling to understand a problem.

I want to list the security packages that need to be updated by yum only on CentOS 6.

I have downloaded an old version of CentOS 6

```
[root@server ~]# cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS Linux release 6.0 (Final)
[root@server ~]# uname -a
Linux server 2.6.32-71.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri May 20 03:51:51 BST 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Then I installed

```
[root@server ~]# yum install yum-plugin-security
```

Now I expect to be able to run

```
[root@server ~]# yum updateinfo summary
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, presto, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.schlundtech.de
 * extras: centosmirror.netcup.net
 * updates: centos.mirror.net-d-sign.de
updateinfo summary done
```

or

```
[root@server ~]# yum --security check-update
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, presto, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.schlundtech.de
 * extras: centosmirror.netcup.net
 * updates: centos.mirror.net-d-sign.de
Limiting package lists to security relevant ones
No packages needed for security; 174 packages available
```

and receive a list of packages that have security issue that need to be updated. as you can see it doesn't show anything.

Am I going mad? Yum update lists 173 updated packages, but none of them are security related?

Comment: Thanks, I have just read this somewhere else...Damn. So there is no way to tell what is a security patch as opposed to a feature patch on CentOS, just yum update and be done :D

Comment: converted to answer with a reliable source.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Contrary to RHEL, CentOS doesn't tag security on packages: so except for EPEL, you don't get security-only updates, as is explaining this answer on CentOS forums: [how to install security patches in Centos](https://forums.centos.org/viewtopic.php?t=59369)

> Re: how to install security patches in Centos
>
> Post by TrevorH » 2016/09/19 09:32:02
>
> Just run yum update on a regular
>   basis and you will automatically get security updates.
>
> If you are referring to the ability to run e.g. yum --security update
>   then **you are out of luck as CentOS does not supply the necessary data
>   in the yum repositories to allow the yum -plugin-security plugin to
>   work at all**. It does not work.

Note that TrevorH is part of the [CentOS team](https://wiki.centos.org/Team) and working on the Fora (ie: forums)