# Are security updates applied with `dnf update` or is it separate procedure in Linux?

Tags: linux, security, hacking, centos9

I found this vulnerability with `polkit`. It was found in Jan 22. How does keeping Linux updated security wise works in general?

If I run `dnf update` on CentOS9 - will it fix it? Or shall I look into each and every vulnerability myself and fix it manually?

[image]

Comment: it says `CentOS9` in the text and in the tag. -\o/-

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should fix it.
Errata are of three types: bug, security and enhancements.
with dnf update, you will get all of them.
You can filter as well; for e.g., to check only for security updates, run:
`dnf check-update --security`
and you can apply them with:
`dnf update --security`

Comment: I don't know if this is still relevant since CentOS became part of RedHat and its usecase was changed from clone to upstream beta release, but before this, CentOS7 (contrary to RHEL7) didn't tag security updates, meaning you had to apply *all* updates to get *security* updates. See this Q/A: [Update CentOS Security Patches](https://serverfault.com/questions/996189/update-centos-security-patches)